# Bitwise operators order of precedence

Tags: bitmap, logic, bit-manipulation, operator-precedence

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) the bitwise AND operator has higher precedence than the bitwise OR. However wolfram says they are equivalent. Are the following two expressions equivalent?

```
C &  A | B
C & (A | B)
```

My thoughts are that they are the same since I believe | and & have  the same precedence, so we just evaluate left to right.

Comment: The order of operations will depend on the language. I plugged [`c AND a OR b`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+c+and+a+or+b) into Wolfram Alpha and it gives me `(c AND a) OR b`. Also [`c OR a AND b`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+c+or+a+and+b) gives me `c OR (a AND b)` so it does look like in Wolfram Alpha `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. These are logical operators instead of bitwise, but I think they'd follow the same pattern.

Comment: @NullUserException I guess that indirectly raises a possibly interesting point: in C and C++ the logical operations always explicitly evaluate from left to right and evaluation ends as soon as the result is known (so in any `&&` the right side is not evaluated if the left side evaluates to zero; in any `||` the right side is not evaluated if the left side evaluates to non-zero). The bitwise operators have precedence and no special rules about avoid evaluation of subexpressions.

Comment: You can see &, ^ and | as the bitwise versions of, respectively, multiplication, addition and maximum. That sort of justifies their most widely used precedences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory any language or logic system could dictate the precedence of its operators. However, in all languages I am familiar with, bitwise (and logical, for that matter) AND has higher precedence than OR.

Given that & and | are fundamental operators and, crucially, (a & b)  | c = d does not imply a & (b | c) =d, it seems very unlikely that any real language would leave their relative precedence undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they have a natural precedence, unlike say multiplication and division being of greater precedence than subtraction and addition because they can be built from subtraction and addition.

[In C `&` has higher precedence than `|`](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) so your two statements are not equivalent. I'd guess most languages with C-like syntax will inherit from that.

Answer (score 1):

If you give Wolfram Alpha '|' and '&' it will translate it into bitwise functions like BitAnd(x,y) and BitOr(x,y). The expression of binary operators is ambiguous, but it gets changed into functions which are not ambiguous.

Example: `1 & 2 | 3`  will get changed into `BitOr[BitAnd[1,2],3]`, and there is only one way to evaluate those functions. As above commenters noted, Alpha is putting & above | in precedence.

Link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%26+2+%7C+3

Interestingly, this feature of translating binary operators '|' and '&' appears to be ***undocumented*** as it does not appear in any of the standard Wolfram guides to their operators.

Ref1: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html

Ref2: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BitwiseOperations.html

Some examples for bitwise operators from other languages, high->low

- Python: and, xor, or
- C++: and, xor, or
- Golang: and, xor == or (left associative)
- Pascal: and, or
- Swift: and, xor == or (left associative)
- Dart: and, xor, or
- Javascript: and, xor, or

Refs:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BitwiseOperations.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators_and_Delimiters
- http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/about-us/104-wiki/pascal-basics/chapter-1/118-pascal-operators
- https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/swift_standard_library_operators
- http://www.dartlang.cc/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.pdf
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/precedence_operators.shtml